# Ascii to raster error

Tags: python, typeerror, arcpy

I am new to python. I have this code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace

env.workspace = "\C:\Users\kfi179\Desktop\rgccsdaily2013"
outWorkspace = "C:\Users\kfi179\Desktop\Texas)"
dataType = "FLOAT"


#Check out the Arcgis Spatial Anaylst extension licence
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get a list of ascii
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.txt"): 

    #Print raster list
    print file
    outputraster = file[0:12] + ".tif"
    #Save TIF
    #outRaster.save(output)
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(file,outputraster,dataType)
```

and keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kfi179\Desktop\AsciiToRaster.py", line 17, in <module>
    for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.txt"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems `arcpy.ListFiles("*.txt")` return None instead of a file list. I noticed your env is set to `"\C:\Users\kfi179\Desktop\rgccsdaily2013"`. I think you have a backslash at the beginning which make the file list fail. Also, backslashes need to be escaped. Might be better to use forward slashes

`"C:/Users/kfi179/Desktop/rgccsdaily2013"`